# installed tesserocr(python) can't see leptonica

Tags: linux, python-3.x, shared-libraries, leptonica

I have installed leptonica and tesseract in $HOME/local and tesseract is working properly, then tesserocr python package with:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/home/user/local/include /home/user/local/lib" pip install tesserocr
```

and when I want to invoke it I get this:

```
$ python3 extract.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI, RIL, PyLTRResultIterator, iterate_level
ImportError: liblept.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

please help

Comment: your `CPPFLAGS` aren't valid, try `CPPFLAGS="-I/home/user/local/include -L/home/user/local/lib"`

Comment: Thanks, this helped

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment on the original post, the proper installation command should be:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/home/user/local/include -L/home/user/local/lib" pip install tesserocr
```